# Как сделать запись из БД в php

Tags: php, mysql

PHP Notice: Undefined index: role in /var/www/portal.testlab01.local/public_html/cabinet.php on line 41, referer: portal.testlab01.local/index.php

Пытаюсь сделать так, но понимаю, что это не правильно.

```
<?php
$link= mysqli_connect("localhost", "phpmyadmin", "Super2021", "Web-Portal");
$role = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `role` DESC");
?>
```

Вот для этого я хочу сделать:

```
<?php
$CAN_CRUD = ["2", "3"];
if (in_array($_SESSION['role'], $CAN_CRUD))
{
    echo'<a href="admin-panel.php">Админ панель</a>';
}
else
{
    echo'<a href="index.php">Вы не админ</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: посмотрите хотя бы комментарии - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: mysqli коннект...mysql запрос..сильно

Answer (score 0):

Проверь наличие элемента в массиве `isset`

```
if (isset($_SESSION['role']) && in_array($_SESSION['role'], $CAN_CRUD)) {

}
```